# Find number of subsets in $\{1!, 2!, \ldots, k!\}$ such that the sum is divisible by $k$

Tags: number-theory

Question: Find number of subsets in $\{1!, 2!, \ldots, k!\}$ such that the sum is divisible by $k$

Context: Watched a 3b1b video yesterday, thought this question would be interesting

Attempt:
For $k > 3$:

$$2! = 3!  \mod 4$$

$$1! = 3!  \mod 5$$

$$3! = 4! \mod 6$$

$$1! = 5! \mod 7$$

and so on and so forth, my point is there will be numbers $a$, $b$ such that $a! = b! \mod k$ where $a, b < k$ and $k > 3$

how do I continue without knowing what are the numbers described above?

Comment: Naive approach... Find a "smallest subset" of each length $\ell=1,2,3\dots$ which is divisible as described, then count the number of repetitions of that subset by the other subsets that are disjoint but also divisible...

Comment: would you mind giving an example of how that helps achieving the real result?

Comment: The naive label is meant to suggest that this is likely a very calculations-intense approach.  That said, suppose $k=3$, then we have subsets $\{\},\{[1,2,3]\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}$ and we can say that $\{3\}$ is the sole example of length $1$, and $\{1,2\}$ is solo for length $2$, and these together make the length $3$ subset, giving three total meeting the condition.

Comment: oh, thanks, now i understand what do you mean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't think this is an easy problem nor a problem with any closed form, since it depends on the number of $n$ such that $k \mid n!$. Restricting to $n = p$ prime, we get the following data:

```
sage: for n in prime_range(2, 101):
....:     print(f'{n:2} {str(f(n)).ljust(28)} = {str(factor(f(n)))}')
....:
 2 2                            = 2
 3 4                            = 2^2
 5 6                            = 2 * 3
 7 16                           = 2^4
11 172                          = 2^2 * 43
13 632                          = 2^3 * 79
17 7708                         = 2^2 * 41 * 47
19 27602                        = 2 * 37 * 373
23 364744                       = 2^3 * 127 * 359
29 18512728                     = 2^3 * 13 * 17 * 37 * 283
31 69272820                     = 2^2 * 3^4 * 5 * 61 * 701
37 3714564118                   = 2 * 1857282059
41 53634713538                  = 2 * 3 * 7 * 1277016989
43 204560391884                 = 2^2 * 51140097971
47 2994414646150                = 2 * 5^2 * 19 * 53^2 * 1122113
53 169947155749830              = 2 * 3 * 5 * 157 * 1613 * 2731 * 8191
59 9770521217528634             = 2 * 3 * 1628420202921439
61 37800705069111514            = 2 * 850033 * 22234845629
67 2202596307308624870          = 2 * 5 * 862861 * 255266642867
71 33256101992043617480         = 2^3 * 5 * 401 * 16229 * 43943 * 2907271
73 129379903640264225446        = 2 * 9833 * 6578862180426331
79 7651429238067280809480       = 2^3 * 3^2 * 5 * 17 * 89 * 211 * 66576150787151
83 116522970565265462167274     = 2 * 79 * 33889 * 21761844712926427
89 6954719321827979072474512    = 2^4 * 131 * 383 * 11419829 * 758629897721
97 1633570361118852321515795564 = 2^2 * 7 * 14423 * 21569909293 * 187532218567
```

---

However, some trivial analysis can be performed. If we assume that $n!$ mod $k$ is uniformly distributed between $[0, k)$, then each residue class has $\frac{n}{k}$ numbers. Through some probability calculations you can show that the subset sums will then also be uniformly distributed across the residue classes. In particular, a subset sum has probability $\frac{1}{k}$ of being divisible by $k$, and

$$
f(n) \sim \frac{2^k}{k}
$$

Numerical calculations up to $n = 1200$ shows that $\left|\frac{\log_2(p) + \log_2(f(p))}{p} - 1\right| \to 0$

---

I know this is like the worst possible approximation you can make but as I stated above, it is quite a hard problem.

Also, OEIS gives nothing.

Comment: ok, thanks for the input

Comment: Added some analysis to make it less "low-effort"

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suspect, after computing the count for lots of values of $k$, that there is no closed-form (i.e. "nice") answer.

A couple observations:

- For prime $k$, the answer tends to be very close to $2^k/k$, as one would expect (if every subset has sum divisible by $k$ with "probability" $k$). It actually seems to be a lot closer than I would expect -- if you take a random list of $k$ integers in $[0,k)$ and compute the number of subsets (out of the $2^k$) with sum $0\pmod k$, you'd expect it to differ from $2^k/k$ by about $\sqrt{2^k/k}$, but the difference seems to be closer to $2^{k/6}$ for large $k$, or even smaller. I'm not sure why this is; it would be very interesting to have a reason.
- For composite $k$, most of the numbers $\{1!,2!,\dots,k!\}$ are $0$ modulo $k$, so the number of subsets is $2^{\text{number of zeros}}$ times some small-ish number. This observation allows computation of the exact number in some cases. For example, when $k=j!$, only the first $j-1$ terms are nonzero modulo $k$; since
  $$1!+2!+3!+\cdots+(j-1)!<j!,$$
  the only possible sums are those containing some subset of $\{j!,\dots,k!\}$, and thus there are exactly $2^{k-j+1}=2^{j!-j+1}$ subsets with zero sum modulo $k$. The same argument works for numbers like $k=j!/2$ for $j>3$.

---

Here is a quick way to compute the count given $k$, which runs in $O(k^2)$ time (assuming all computations are $O(1)$; when $k$ is very large, this is probably an unreasonable assumption, and the runtime should bump up to about $O(k^3)$):

1. Compute the list $[1!\bmod k,2!\bmod k,3!\bmod k,\dots,k!\bmod k]$, since all that matters for whether subset sums are divisible by $k$ is their residues modulo $k$.
2. Initialize a list $Q_0=[1,0,\dots,0]$ of length $k$. For each $0\leq j<k$ and $0\leq i\leq k$, the entry $Q_i[j]$ will store the number of subsets of $\{1!,2!,\dots,i!\}$ have sum $j\bmod k$.
3. For each $0\leq i<k$, compute $Q_{i+1}$ from $Q_i$, by setting
   $$Q_{i+1}[j]=Q_i[j]+Q_i[(j-i!)\bmod k],$$
   using the precomputed residue $i!\bmod k$. The $Q_i[j]$ term counts subsets that do not contain $i!$, while the other term counts subsets that contain $i!$.
4. Once $Q_k$ has been computed, the answer is $Q_k[0]$.

This can be sped up for many $k$ by counting the number $N$ of $0$s in the list $[1!\bmod k,\dots,k!\bmod k]$, ignoring those $i$ for which $k\mid i!$ in step 3, and multiplying by $2^N$ at the end, since all those $i$ do is double every element of the array in step 3. This reduces the time significantly for $k$ with lots of prime factors, since

For prime $k$ about $2000$ (where the last speedup is irrelevant), an implementation of this algorithm in Python runs in about one second on my computer, and it's much faster for smaller $k$. For numbers with a lot of prime factors, like powers of $2$, this can be pushed up much higher: my program takes about five seconds on $k=2^{20}$, which is about one million.

Comment: I don't think it will go to $O(k^3)$. Your first step is $O(k)$ if you take modulo every step, and 3rd step only involves addition, which is $O(\log k)$ at most, so worst case would be $O(k^2\log k)$.

Comment: @GarethMa The third step involves addition of numbers which are about $k$ bits in length, and so the additions take $O(k)$ time (although in practice it shouldn't be that bad, unless $k$ is large enough that the rest of the algorithm would be impractical anyway). Also, this is really only for numbers with large prime divisors, as if you can cut off at some $k'$ then both the number of times you need to run step 3 and the size of the numbers are bounded by $k'$ (giving a runtime $O(k'^2k)$), not $k$.

Comment: My bad. I have the same algorithm as you.